# How to Shrink a Partion with data in the beginning

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, gparted

I installed `Ubuntu 20.04` six Months ago and my Issue is, I installed Ubuntu with custom partition schema (created partitions myself) as this:
My Partition Table
[image]

And Because I do development (and curious to test OSS projects usually), **20GB** in the **/home** is not enough and very often I have to move things around to other partitions which obviously gonna delete them soon because I just experimenting with'em anyway.

> I seperated **/home** and **/root** just because if I messed up smth in the system my personal files will be safe (hopefully).

I wanted to be to shrink the **/root** partition which is *~260GB* in order to increase **/home** which is *20GB* partition, but it seems impossible as the data in **/root** is stored in the beginning of the partition so I can't grow the **/home** partition.

Hence, I read about that, Linux systems use files as **swap** nowadays, I thought I could delete that partition but also afraid of losing data if I grow the **/home** partition in the beginning.

I thought that no place is better to ask! if there is another option to move the data far from the beginning so I can resize the partitions at either side safely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Fun Fact 1`: I solved my problems after last day of college today. wanted to share it with you.

`Fun Fact 2`: I did **everything** without any sort of *backup*, it was **DANGEROUS** and not recommended (highly discouraged, in fact).

So what I did was simple but a little bit dangerous:

#### what I did?

1. Shrink-ed an 80GiB of `sda7` aka **root** partition on the right end (it was ~260GiB) with resulting

   | Home: `~20GiB` | root `180GiB` | unallocated `~80GiB` |
2. Moved the **root** partition to the right, so the resulting scheme will be:

   | Home: `~20GiB` | unallocated `~80GiB` | root `180GiB` |
3. Grow-ed the **home** `sda6` partition to extend all the way up to the edge of the root partition (extending by all the remaining unallocated space, resulting scheme:

   | Home: `~100GiB` | root `180GiB` |

#### How did I do it?

1. I used an Ubuntu 18 stable with a live boot USB stick (because partitions have to be unmounted and it was not possible with normal setup because the system was on which I was wanted to edit).
2. I used [GParted](https://gparted.org/), a graphical application helps you shrink/move and many many more things graphically with a very stable and clear procedure.

#### References:

1. Resize Partition with GParted: https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-resize-partition
2. Move Partitions with GParted: https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-move-partition